# Maven: Load dynamically the modules (super pom)

Tags: maven, module, pom.xml

The idea is I have a lot of Maven projects following a naming convention, i.e :

- projectA
- projectB
- projectC

Is it possible to dynamically load all the modules in the super POM, i.e :

```
<modules>
    <module>project*</module>
</modules>
```

I would like to avoid referencing by hand all the project name in the super POM.

Thank you

Comment: Are those childs related projects or independent?

Comment: I would say independent, but they share dependencies.